# How to clean and build a library before debugging another project in codeblocks?

Tags: unit-testing, codeblocks

In the codeblocks IDE I have now a main project which creates a libmyclasses.a

Now I'm testing the main project via an additional projet where I'm using unittest++. This project compiles and all includes are properly setup and linking is fine - except:

when I'm doing a change in the main project codeblocks won't automatically recreate the libmyclasses.a before executing the tests. When I'm *rebuilding* the test project then the main projects gets recompiled as it is a dependency already, but the main project does not recreate the libmyclasses.a !?

How can I force the recreation of this library?

Or how can I post execute the test project after the main project?

Comment: is `libmyclasses.a` produced by a separate project that depends on main project or is this library actually a target of main project itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally used a different way:
I'm now compiling the tests directly in my Debug build target and excluded tests file in Release. Thats faster, easier and without that clean&build problem. (BTW: The main.cpp is only added to the release target.)

In theory one could go a third way and put the tests even closer to the classes via a preprocessor directive:

```
#ifndef TESTING
```

but this could lead to bloated classes etc. Let me know if you know a better way, although it looks very good now, I can quickly test it, debug it etc.